# CPU voltage settings set in BIOS always stay the default

Tags: bios, voltage

Default voltage is 1.5v.It can be set to the highest setting (1.55) or even to 0.8v but the voltage always is 1.5v.

How to make it 1.55v?

Can I somehow make it higher than listed there (like 1.6v) even though highest is 1.55?

Comment: Why you want to do that ?

Comment: @Tom to overclock the CPU (make it faster) instead of buying new CPU

Comment: It will be a risk to make the voltage higher than 1.55 V.

Comment: @Tom even if my idle temp are 16 Celsius and 100% load is 28 Celsius ?

Answer (score 0):

That limit is set by the cpu.  I remember a while ago with the older P4's there was a voltage hack you could do by connecting 2 or more of the CPU pins together, but i havent heard anything about that in quite some time.