# How to overclock CPU using only FSB?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, overclocking, voltage

According to my BIOS the CPU temperature and the system temperature are 16°C and 18°C respectively for Idle on stock air cooling.  (It used to be 40°C and 48°C when I kept my computer inside a case. Now I have computer outside on desk).

Under 100% load for long time the temperature increases to 28°C and 35°C.

I want to overclock my CPU as it is the biggest bottleneck. It is running at 100% most of the time.

I cannot change the voltage to the CPU because the new setting is always ignored (see the issue [here](https://superuser.com/questions/738286/cpu-voltage-settings-set-in-bios-always-stay-the-default)).

I am not worried about temperature but about voltage:
**Q1: Can voltage alone harm anything? Or is it just temp?**

I updated the BIOS to the last version for this motherboard and I can only overclock by increasing the FSB. The highest stable I got for K8T NEO FSR is 214 from 200.

**Q2: If I increase GHz by 10% should I increase voltage by 10% too?**

Comment: How cold is the room you are in? 12°C? 

Any hotter and I suspect that the BIOS is wrong about the CPU temp and system temp because the CPU wll be hotter than the environment it is in. Even if it is only 5°C hotter when it is idle and with good cooling.  That makes the 16°C and 18°C numbers suspect.

Comment: @Hennes I have no idea except that it is warm (at least for Me) How can I know real temp if BIOS is lying?

Comment: You can not :(. 

But regular air cooling can only cool down to room temperature. It will never cool your CPU below that. Peltier elements are an exception to that, but you wrote that you are on stock air cooling.  That means that if your room is a normal 20°C then your CPU will be 20°C or hotter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can voltage alone harm anything? Or is it just temp?

Yes. Enough voltage increase can fry a CPU. It is unlikely that you can set such an high voltage though.

> If I increase GHz by 10% should I increase voltage by 10% too?

No. As a rule you do not want to increase the voltage unless absolutely necessary.

When overclocking heat is bad. A higher voltage leads to more heat and you should use the lowest voltage possible needed for the system to run stable. Usually this is the default voltage. The exception is when you seriously overclock the CPU (more than 10%). Then more voltage might be needed.

How much more varies per CPU and even varies within the same model of CPU's. There are entire sites describing how to OC and there is no way I can summarize all that information in just one post. However I can say it is not a 1:1 relation. E.g. 10% OC does not equal 10% more voltage needed.

Comment: OK thanks, how to increase the voltage for cpu if setting gets ignored?