# My PSU makes a VERY LOUD NOISE when watching video in Firefox browser

Tags: video, power-supply

After Firefox update now every time I watch video I have very loud noise from PSU. It is so loud that the first time I heard it I got scared.

My friend told me not use a "stable" but get an Alpha. Friend says Alpha is always better than Beta and other, like Alpha male instead of Beta male or Stable.

So he installed the Alpha for Me and now the the PSU is loud when watching video and remains loud even after closing Firefox!

> 1. I have an old computer which worked fine.
> 2. I am trying to overclock it and as a result it is using more power.
> 3. When I also
>      watch a video in my now OC'd computer (thus using both more power from
>      the main board and high power for the graphics) my old PSU starts to
>      make a loud noise.

Comment: Your friends needs to get a clue. Alfa versions of software are test versions. They often add more features and add old (known) bugs. But they also are untested and often contain new bugs. It is never 'always better' or 'always worse.

Comment: Are you 100% positive the noise is coming from the PSU? If so, I'd strongly suggest replacing it. There's no reason a PSU should make a lot of noise. Is it a whooshing sound? A scraping sound? A whirring sound?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes Im 100% positive it s coming from the PSU.It is more like a (hard to describe accurately) high-pitched buzzing chainsaw being rapidly vibrated.

Comment: @fdsfgdsdf Sounds like a bad fan. I'd replace the PSU unless you're capable of replacing the fan (or know someone who is).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if I avoid watching videos should I still replace the fan?

Comment: @fdsfgdsdf Definitely. It's probably going to fail completely soon.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks very much for all your help.Id upvote you but my rep is too low.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a hardware upgrade. Probably the machine is truggling to render the video due to old hardware.

Comment: It stutters at 720p and video is lagging behind audio starting from 360p sometimes 480p.Im anting to overclock it but no answers my question here:http://superuser.com/questions/738286/cpu-voltage-settings-set-in-bios-always-stay-the-default and http://superuser.com/questions/738291/how-to-overclock-cpu-using-only-fsb

Comment: Try to see if there is dust acumulated... clean it with the vacuum cleaner.

Comment: Note: If you clean it make sure that you do not rapidly spin the fan due to air flow.

Comment: @Lyhan please see my questions about overclocking efforts.They also say that my temps are 16 and 18 Celsius idle because I keep computer outside case on desk.Also will vacuuming PC discharge static electricity to PC?

Comment: @Hennes please see my other questions (they also have more info about computer)

Comment: You might want to add this to your original post: (use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/738300/edit) link).

 1. I have an old computer which worked fine.
 2. I am trying to overclock it and as a result it is using more power.
 3. When I also watch a video in my now OC'd computer (thus using both more power from the main board and high power for the graphics) my old PSU starts to make a loud noise.

Comment: Note regarding the Vaccuuming of PC: It is safe in regards to static electricity. I would though be careful and wear an antistatic wrist strap to manipulate the motherboard, specially if your have a rug or carpet on the floor.